# BridgedAdapter of VirtualBox on Red Hat 7 stopped working

Tags: redhat-enterprise-linux, virtualbox

I have a VirtualBox VM (running Red Hat 7) on my Red Hat 7, using a *Bridged Adapter* for its networking. It stopped working yesterday; the NetworkManager on the VM was unable to obtain a DHCP lease for its network interface, due to the DHCP requests being unanswered, leading (eventually) to a time-out.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the problem was caused by having out of date kernel modules for VirtualBox on the host. I fixed this problem by running

```
 sudo /etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup
```

then rebooting.

VirtualBox makes use of some kernel modules, including some modules for handling network I/O for guests. The VirtualBox [documentation](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch02.html#externalkernelmodules) recommends using the `dkms` software to automatically rebuild those modules when necessary. Unfortunately, Red Hat 7 does not have that package. It is available from the [Fedora EPEL](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL) repository, but I could not get that to work. Running that `vboxdrv setup` rebuilds the kernel modules manually.